# jquery UI datepicker flickering the "other" date in a range selection scenario

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I seem to have a slight problem on the datepicker. Basically I am implementing an example like the date-range in the jquery UI sample site. Everything works ok but I get a strange behaviour: when I pick any date, the calendar flashes for a moment showing the other calendar selected date and then disappears. I know it's not a big deal but it is apparently annoying for our client.

I wanted to put a code example here but then noticed that the same behaviour is visible in the [datepicker sample page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range).

Does anybody know if it is a known problem with jquery? it seems to happen cross-browser as well...

Comment: Looks like a bug with datepicker.  You could set `showAnim:""` to disable the animations so you don't get a chance to see the update flash.

Comment: That is a good workaround thanks! :) it would be nice to see if they fix the problem with the datepicker.

Comment: Thanks Nal! Your suggestion is still helping to avoid this still unfixed issue with jQui 1.10 (May 2013!). If you post your comment as solution you'll get my vote! ;-)